# Integrals without terms possible?

Tags: integration, notation

Is an integral without *a term* possible? I don't know the specific name for the term at the end but here is an example:

$\int x $

vs

$\int$$ (x) dx$

And does $\int$$ ((x) dx) \Rightarrow  \frac{(1/2)x^2*x}{x}  = \frac{1}{2} x^2  $ ?

if so does $\int (x)  = \frac{ (1/2) x^2 }{x} = \frac{1}{2} x  $ ?

This is basically reversing the chain rule : $ \frac{d}{dx} (x^2) = \frac{2xdx}{dx} = 2x$

But without in terms of anything so :  $d (x^2) = 2x dx$ (I think that is an infinitesimal)

I am asking if it is possible to do calculus without the change being in terms? I can't imagine a useful scenario but I'm asking if it is systematically correct. Mostly I ask this because I'm confused as to where the $dx$ at the end of integrals disappears to.

Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: It depends on your definitions and interpretations. Unless you are dealing with differential forms, you could probably just interpret that $dx$ to mean "integrate with respect to x". If you define clearly the function you are integrating and the set you are integrating it over, there are alternate notations you can use that don't use $dx$. Differential forms are another thing entirely.

Comment: This question isn't stupid but it is complicated and I'm not really qualified to talk about the historical meaning of $dx$ or the formulation of differential forms.

Comment: @Vaste Vec You may want to read about Riemann Sums to understand the role of $dx$

Answer (score 0):

$dx$ is sometimes omitted if the variable is understood. For example, if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, you can write
$$ \int_a^b f(x)\,dx \equiv \int f
$$
The bounds of integration are also omitted since it is natural to integrate over the domain of $f$.

However, don't use it if $f$ depends on several variables, or when you want to make a change of variable. It can also be confused with indefinite integration, (a.k.a. antidifferentiation) so use it with care.

The role of $dx$ is a placeholder to hint which variable you want to integrate over, and it is not a "infinitesimal" unless you are using nonstandard analysis.

Answer (score 0):

f is a function (or in other words a differential 0-form), f dx is a differential 1-form, f dx dy is a differential two-form, and so forth.  The integral of a 1-form over a one-dimensional space is a 0-form.

You can't integrate a 0-form, because you'd have to get a (-1)-form.